# Which is more suitable, XMPP or Channel API for a chat system in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm confused which of the two:XMPP or Channel API (Google App Engine) is more suitable for the requirement: "Users of the application (authentication: google account) should be able to chat other users"

To chat with other XMPP client is not part of the requirement.

If the application will have hundreds or thousands of users (using chat feature), will the quota of Channel API can handle it?

Can AJAX alone do the requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMPP API is for sending messages from Google App Engine to any XMPP client - like the Google Chat client in Gmail.

Channel API is for sending a message from the Google App Engine instance to your user's browser.  It's a "push" message.

As long as you pay for it, yes, but calculate the cost.

You can send a message from a browser to the App Engine with AJAX, but you need Channel API to send the message from App Engine back to your browser.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very brief list of the strengths and weaknesses of each that I know of:

**XMPP**

- Open, mature, well-known, and well-documented.
- Made specifically for chat, but flexible enough to do other things.
- Uses XML (strength for some, weakness for others).
- Notorious for having relatively high latency.
- [Clients](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) in plenty of languages (including JavaScript).

**Channels API**

- App engine proprietary
- Less latency
- Not "made" for chat.  You may have to engineer some things on top of this.

The deciding factor that I would make a decision on is how much of a problem latency is for you.  I would strongly advise doing some benchmarking to figure out how bad the latency will be for your application and make the decision from there.